# How to write a matches for input that contains alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I have a problem with my `matches`. I have a field that that SHOULD accept a value that may contain any combination of `alphanumeric and special characters`. I have a code that works fine when the input is a `1) combination of alphanumeric and special characters, and 2) alphanumeric`. But if the input contains a combination of either `1) number and special characters ONLY without alphabet or 2) alphabet and special characters ONLY without number`, I got an error on my `matches`. What I wanted to do is to create a `matches` that best works on the following input combinations:

```
1) alphabet+number
2) alphabet+special character
3) alphabet+number+special character
4) number+special character
```

This is my code:

```
matches: /^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z_\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)~!@#%&-=]{8,}$/
```

I need your suggestions! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your positive lookahead requires *both* a `[0-9]` to be present *and* a `[a-zA-Z]` to be present.

Try reducing this to one single lookahead, which just specifies that *at least one* of `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z]` be present:

```
matches: /^(?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z_\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)~!@#%&-=]{8,}$/
```

Furthermore, you can improve on the efficiency of the regex by modifying the `.*` in your lookahead to be `[^0-9a-zA-Z]*`: that way the lookahead matches the *first* alphanumeric it finds and then stops, preventing needless scanning:

```
matches: /^(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9a-zA-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z_\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)~!@#%&-=]{8,}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]+.*)[_\[\]\\\^\$\.\|\?\*\+\(\)~!@#%&-=]{8,}$/
```

Comment: It's not clear why you have ".*" at the very start since you are expecting alphanumeric. So you may choose to remove them.

Comment: They do not expect alphanumeric at the start - the `.*[a-zA-Z0-9]` means they expect *at least one* alphanumeric in the entire string.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge! The answer of mathematical.coffee works perfectly just fine!